# How to post a form to two different page and use form data in the submitted page?

Tags: php, forms

What I am trying to do is I have a form which inserts data into a table. But now I want to add a preview button to the form to show a preview of the data to be inserted and uploader can check the formatting he has done before inserting data.

Now I want to know how to submit form to two different pages and use the form data.

I am confused as Using action attribute of form will make both buttons to POST to same page.

I have also tried code below, but it will also fail if the data is too much and as data3 is paragraph and can have long essay data

```
if( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['preview']) ){
    $data1 = trim($_POST['data1']);
    $data2 = trim($_POST['data2']);
    $data3 = trim($_POST['data3']);
    header("location: preview.php?preview=true&data1=$data1&data2=$data2&data3=$data3");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: You will be having two buttons, one for saving immediately and one for previewing before saving right?

Comment: @Swellar yes there are two buttons

Comment: if $data3 is a paragraph . i think you can store into  session and get into another page

Comment: use javascript for the preview. It can collect the current values in the form fields and be used to generate the formatted page without actually posting the data.

Comment: maximum size of session variable is 128MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a session, and store the post data in an array, or output the variables in a hidden form on preview page.

Example 1:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['form_data'] = [
    'data1' => $_POST['data1']
    ...
];
```

Example 2:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="data1" value="', htmlspecialchars($_POST['data1']), '" />';
```

Comment: at the end you should destroy the session.

Comment: @BilalAhmed From the help page: `Note: You do not have to call session_destroy() from usual code. Cleanup $_SESSION array rather than destroying session data.`.

Comment: yes, i agree with you. i think you mention this in your answer because in $data1 have a paragraph......

Comment: @FrankerZ can you also tell me when should I unset this session array?

Comment: @programmingArrow You can use `session_unset()` when you're done with your data, or simply just let it expire out when the session is destroyed naturally within php.